# Outlook add to internal link in email "file:///"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, links

Since a week ago outlook chnaged his behaviour and started to add to the link used for the locall network "file://" and made impossible to open files on local network, someone has a solution?

i tried to find a solution in the options but i didn't found anything

i added a screenshot of the error, this happen only with the desktop old version of outlook, with the new on doesn't happen

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYmsd.png)

Comment: "file://" means that this is file, so it's correct. What exactly are you doing that doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide screenshots of the relevant error?

Comment: I am writing to see if there is any progress on the issue. If you have any questions or need further help on this, feel free to post back.